# Is there a way to convert a .lst file into an excel spreadsheet to sort data then convert back to the original format?

Tags: export-to-excel, txt

I use software called Audatex to manage car damage repairs. Part of the software includes data which contains various repair information. This changes every week and i am sent a .lst file containing all the latest information. The problem is when i receive the file and import it into the system there is no way to organise the data within the software. I would like to be able to convert the .lst file into a text document, import that data into an excel worksheet, sort the data into things like alphabetical etc and then export the data back into a text file with the same format as the original .lst file just with the lines in the order sorted within excel.

This is an example of a few lines in the format i usually recieve them and how they display when opened as a text file.

```
AS           BMW                 1000 9 KDS                                                                               Specialist               27500                                S           GENERAL             1000 9 SRS RESET                                                                         Specialist               12500                                S           GENERAL             1000 9 PDC RESET                                                                         Specialist               12500                                S           GENERAL             1000 9 E.P.A. CHARGE                                                                     ALLOWANCE                1265                                 S           GENERAL             1000 9 CAR CARE KIT                                                                      ALLOWANCE                400                                  S           AUDI                1000 9 GEOMETRY                                                                          Specialist               24500                                I           GENERAL             1000   PULLING REAR PANELS                                                               .               10
```

The columns as displayed in the software are Guide No (always 1000), Rep type - shows as a single letter in the file but in system shows as various values such as E is Renew,I is Repair Etc, Next Column is Description, Group, Text, Value, WU.

From just counting the characters i found without the first two characters in the Lst file each line is 183 characters and columns separate at positions 0, 12, 32, 37, 39, 121, 146

I dont have much experience working with conversions like this at all so probably approaching this all wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am no expert so have been struggling mostly with converting back to the original format. So far i managed to create a worksheet within excel by removing the first two characters and then separating the data into its respective rows and columns using the below

let

```
Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\CSDud\Downloads\NSPAUSW txt.txt"), null, null, 1252)}), 

#"Split Column by Position" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(183), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"), 

#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Position",{{"Column1", type text}}), 

#"Split Column by Positions" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 12, 32, 37, 39, 121, 146}), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5", "Column1.6", "Column1.7"}), 

#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Positions",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.4", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.5", type text}, {"Column1.6", type text}, {"Column1.7", Int64.Type}})
```

Although definitely not ideal this at least allowed me to view and sort the data into a better order and kept the original lines relatively intact but i have no idea how i would go about getting this to export into the original format. Whatever file type i choose to export as it always separates the lines with a tab.

Comment: There are better ways to sort things than exporting to and from an Excel file.

Comment: Im open to any suggestion, i receive this file every week and has around 16000 lines so just being able to organise then create the same format so i can import it into the system